# Parâmetros em form action não são enviados por método GET

Tags: php, html

Uni vários GET na mesma URL sem problemas, todos usando BUTTON.

http://localhost/teste/escolha_dia.php?inst=teste&sala=sala01&ano=2016&mes=janeiro
usando

```
<?php
$acao = $_GET['inst'];
$acao2 = $_GET['sala'];
$acao3 = $_GET['ano'];
$acao4 = $_GET['mes'];
?>
```

O próximo GET seriam 5 checkbox dentro de um FORM. Se eu usar `<form action="confirmar.php" method="get">` então tudo OK, aparece o resultado `http://localhost/teste/confirmar.php?values[]=18&values[]=28&values[]=38`.

Só que eu preciso dos GET anteriores nessa mesma URL para enviar por email.

Eu completo o form action com os GET anteriores.

```
<form action="confirmar.php?&inst=<?=$acao;?>&sala=<?=$acao2;?>&ano=<?=$acao3;?>&mes=<?=$acao4;?>&diahora=<?=$value;?>';"`
```

Na página seguinte insiro os GET:

```
<?php
$acao = $_GET['inst'];
$acao2 = $_GET['sala'];
$acao3 = $_GET['ano'];
$acao4 = $_GET['mes'];
$acao5 = $_GET['diahora'];
?>
```

Quando atualizo o site e clico no botão acusa os erros

> Notice: Undefined index: inst, sala, ano, mes e diahora

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Se puder enviar o GET dos checkbox sem usar form, apenas por button, pode ser também pois não são usuários logados, apenas visitantes do site.

Comment: Quando envio os dados separados tudo funciona. O problema é quando quero enviar os dados dos checkbox juntos com os dados dos button. Aí da erro geral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando usa GET em formulários é necessário repassar os valores pra inputs, assim:

```
<?php
$acao = $_GET['inst'];
$acao2 = $_GET['sala'];
$acao3 = $_GET['ano'];
$acao4 = $_GET['mes'];
$acao5 = $_GET['diahora'];
?>
<form action="confirmar.php">
<input name="inst" value="<?=$acao;?>">
<input name="sala" value="<?=$acao2;?>">
<input name="ano" value="<?=$acao3;?>">
<input name="mes" value="<?=$acao4;?>">
<input name="diahora" value="<?=$acao5;?>">
```

Se for selects terá que fazer algo como (isto é apenas um exemplo pra entender e adaptar):

```
<?php
$options = array(
    'Valor 1' => '1',
    'Valor 2' => '2',
    'Valor 3' => '3',
    'Valor 4' => '4'
);

$campo1 = empty($_GET['campo1']) ? null : $_GET['campo1'];
?>
<form action="">

    <select name="campo1">

    <?php foreach ($options as $descricao => $value): ?>

        <option <?=($campo1 === $value ? ' selected' : '');?> value="<?=$value;?>"><?=$descricao;?></option>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </select>

    <button type="submit">Enviar!</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Está quase pronto. Agora vou fazer um explode p/ fazer um echo desses dados e enviar por email. Cheguei a publicar outra pergunta com essas páginas quase inteiras mas a resposta é a mesma. Muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @ufrrj99 e o que falta?

Comment: Vou tentar fazer os echos e o form de email. Depois vou aprender como fazer o banco de dados e incluir isso tudo junto.

Comment: @ufrrj99 entendo, mas o problema do envio dos inputs você conseguiu resolver com a explicação? Esta enviado agora corretamente?

Comment: Agora está show.

Comment: @ufrrj99 Ah entendi agora, você estava testando, que bom que deu certo. Até mais =)

Answer (score 0):

Dois exemplos simples para resolver:

## ① Botão com evento onclick

Pode resolver simplesmente com um botão com evento "onclick"

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='pagina.php?foo=1&bar=ok';" value="envia">
```

## ② Enviando pelo método POST e resgatando $_GET

Modifique o método GET para POST.

```
<form action="pagina.php?foo=1&bar=ok" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Por quê funciona?

O motivo é que a URL definida no atributo action é sempre enviada pelo método GET, independente do atributo action estar definido como POST.

Esse modo pode ser o mais ideal para o seu caso pois é menos invasivo, ou seja, não fará praticamente nenhuma mudança nos códigos. Apenas precisa trocar *get* por *post* no `action` do `form`