# Aspas duplas na URL

Tags: asp

Estou usando o comando

```
<button class="button button1" value="janeiro" 
  onclick="location.href=
   'escolha_dia.php?inst=<?=$acao;?>&sala=<?=$acao2;?>&ano=<?=$acao3;?>&mes=janeiro';">
Janeiro</button>
```

mas o resultado está vindo com aspas duplas " :

```
http://localhost/teste/confirmar.php?inst=ufruralrj"&sala=ichs_paulo_freire"&ano=2016"&mes=janeiro"
```

Como faço para tirar isso?

Comment: Poderia postar a parte de seu PHP que está gerando as variáveis utilizadas para compor os GET do link? Pois aparentemente essas aspas duplas estão vindo do final de cada variável do PHP e não deveriam existir, nem simples nem dupla.

** Coloca o código contextualizado e tentarei lhe ajudar. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumo que você veio desta resposta de outra pergunta sua:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/121814/

Na postagem original (devidamente corrigida pelo @rodorgas) faltavam aspas no `value`, e como consequência, as aspas do final passaram a fazer parte do valor.

```
<input name="inst" value=<?=$acao;?>">
                         ^-- aqui faltou abrir aspas
```

Experimente assim:

```
<input name="inst" value="<?=$acao;?>">
```

Na verdade, o ideal mesmo é isso:

```
<input name="inst" value="<?php echo htmlentities( $acao );?>">
```

Assim você garante que caracteres especiais serão devidamente tratados, evitando conflito com o HTML.

Comment: Show de bola. Foi só alterar `value="<?php echo htmlentities( $acao );?>">` que sumiram todas as aspas duplas da URL. Muito obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente os valores já estão vindo com aspas duplas, o que é estranho. O ideal seria investigar isso, mas se você quiser simplesmente tratar do jeito que veio, pode fazer assim:

```php
<?php
$acao = 'ufruralrj"';
$acao2 = 'ichs_paulo_freire"';
$acao3 = '2016"';


foreach ($$vars = array(&$acao, &$acao2, &$acao3) as &$var) {
    $var = rtrim($var, '"');
}

echo ("
    <button class=\"button button1\" value=\"janeiro\"
            onclick=\"location.href=escolha_dia.php?inst=$acao&sala=$acao2&ano=$acao3&mes=janeiro\">
        Janeiro
    </button>
    \n");
?>
```